# Is there a way to limit a vim window to show only a portion of a buffer?

Tags: vim

Sometimes when working with big files containing many functions I would like to create some splits showing specific functions and nothing more.

Is it possible in vanilla `vim` or with some plugin to limit the window to show only a region of a buffer?

Just to be clear, currently I open several splits for the same buffer and navigate to the function and that works. but I would like to enhance that by:

1) Not showing the before and after text , to help me focus
2) Locking the windows to that region of text so I cannot accidentally move away (by searching , etc).

Answer (score 3):

The [NrrwRgn - A Narrow Region Plugin similar to Emacs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075) plugin can show parts of the buffer in a separate scratch buffer, with automatic syncing back. That looks like a solution when you're concerned about moving away from the view. Otherwise, I would just size a split window to show exactly what you want, and keep it at that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use folds to fold the portions you do not want to pay attention to.

To create a fold use `v{motion}zf` in visual mode. Use `za` and `zd` to unfold and remove a fold respectively. You can also create folds in command mode. Essentially `{motion}zf`.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VQozxCH7D0) might be a handy reference.